# Why does decimal not work when creating pivot table in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

The following works fine:

```py
a = pandas.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'],
    'B': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    'C': [22.3, 34.0, 12.3]
})

pandas.pivot_table(a, values='C', index='A', columns='B')

B   one  three   two
A                   
a  22.3   12.3   NaN
b   NaN    NaN  34.0
```

But the following returns an empty data frame when pivoted and I am wondering why that is the case:

```py
b = pandas.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'],
    'B': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    'C': [decimal.Decimal('22.3'), decimal.Decimal('34.0'), decimal.Decimal('12.3')]
})

pandas.pivot_table(b, values='C', index='A', columns='B')
                                             
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [a, b]
```

Comment: Interesting. `pivot` works. `pandas.pivot(b, index='A', columns='B', values='C')` very odd indeed.

Comment: `agged = grouped.agg(aggfunc)` [src](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py#L164) returns the empty dataframe. `b.groupby(['A', 'B'], observed=False, sort=True).agg('mean')` handles Decimal incorrectly.

Comment: @HenryEcker seems odd. When I specify `aggfunc=np.sum` I get empty dataframe, but `aggfunc=lambda x: np.sum(x)` works.

Comment: Same is true that `b.groupby(['A', 'B'], observed=False, sort=True).agg(np.mean)` is empty but `b.groupby(['A', 'B'], observed=False, sort=True).agg(lambda s: np.mean(s))` works.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on Python 3.9-3.11, Pandas 1.5.3 or 2.0.1, Ubuntu 22.04. I guess this has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

`b.C` has its `dtype` as `object`. Convert it to numeric and it should work as expected.

```py
b.C = pandas.to_numeric(b.C)
print(pandas.pivot_table(b, values='C', index='A', columns='B'))
```